# how to store xml feed content into database with html tags in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml, rss

I am getting xml feed like this

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <feed  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atoz">
  <entry>
  <title>Php Developer</title>
  <summary type="text">We are required php developer urgently</summary>
  <content type="xhtml">
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p>Spark Infosys is a professional web development  company in Hyderabad</p>
  <p> Requirements are:</p>
  <p>Job Description:</p>
  <ul>
  <li>Must have excellent exposure on technologies like – Php, MYSQL, Html, Ajax, J Query</li>
  <li>Knowledge of Wordpress, Joomla, Magento , codigniter will be an advantag</li>
  <li>Should be proficient in Designing, Developing and Coding skills</li>
 </ul>
  <p>Requirements:</p>
 <ul>
 <li>Must have Minimum 1 Year experience as PHP Developer</li>
 <li>Willing to work niight shifts also</li>
 </ul>              
 </div>
 </content>
 </entry>
 </feed>
```

I am parsing using rss parser.
how to get content tag data with html tags and store in database. present i am not getting

```
 $job_title=mysql_real_escape_string($this->title); 
 $job_summary=mysql_real_escape_string($this->summary);
 $job_content=mysql_real_escape_string($this->content);
```

in content section when i use $this->div then content data is storing with out html tags. when i use $this->content then content data is not inserting in database
Please help me how to store content data with html tags

Comment: What errors are you getting, or what is not working? You have not mentioned anything about that.

Comment: in content section when i use $this->div then content data is storing with out html tags. when i use $this->content then content data is not inserting in database

Comment: Try using [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).